# How to Call Method of statefull Widget out side of the stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I Create stateful Widget Called Globals, (like below code) and I have a method **ChatsCounter()** inside this  stateful Widget, how to Call this method inside  main.dart.out side of  stateful Widget,

I want to Call  ChatsCounter(); inside maind.dart (like below.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    ChatsCounter(); // I want to Call here
  });
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Taxiyee_Messaging_app",
      home: Container(),
    ),
  );
}

**Here is my StatefulWidget :**

      import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
    class Globals extends StatefulWidget {
      const Globals({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _GlobalsState createState() => _GlobalsState();
    }
    
    class _GlobalsState extends State<Globals> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      }
    **//I want to call this method inside main.dart above**
      ChatsCounter() {
        setState(() {
          counter++;
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pick a [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) approach.

Comment: there is no way to call without  state management?? if there is a  way please tell me

Comment: i use GetX how I achive it using GetX

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. create one final variable or var and call it as `_GlobalsState()` and pass it below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final globalState = _GlobalsState();
void main() {
  globalState.chatsCounter();//call this way
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Taxiyee_Messaging_app",
      home: Container(),
    ),
  );
}

class Globals extends StatefulWidget {
  const Globals({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GlobalsState createState() => _GlobalsState();
}

class _GlobalsState extends State<Globals> {
  int counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  chatsCounter() {
    print('Method Call');
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }
}
```